# Что конкретно делает заголовок в HTML <h1>...</h2>

Tags: html, html5, http-заголовки

Прохожу курс и не очень понимаю, что делает этот заголовок. На сколько понял я, он просто меняет размер заголовка в зависимости от его важности

Верно?

Спасибо!

Comment: Размер абсолютно ни при чём, эти теги просто обозначают, что текст внутри них является заголовком, вот и всё

Comment: а для чего тогда нужны h1 h2 h3 h4  и тд?

Comment: Для обозначения заголовков, подзаголовков, подподзаголовков и так далее

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Это сематические теги, они дают понять что происходит у тебя на странице. Представь что бот разбирает веб страницу как книгу. Когда открываешь книгу идет заглавие, там можно вкратце понять что тут происходит и стоит ли вообще тратить время на этот сайт. Важно для SEO продвижение, сразу после Title и Meta Description страницы. Если оформлено не корректно в выдаче сайт может быть хуже чем у конкурентов.

Answer (score -1):

Есть всего 6 тегов. От h1 до h6. Этот тег делает заголовок. h1 - самый большой, а h6 - самый маленький. Закрывающий тег обязателен.